# Cant use firebase reference data type to get subcollection

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I am trying to leverage a reference data type from the profile document to access a subcollection on the referenced clan document.

[image: Profile collection]

[image]

```
    leaveClan() {
  console.log(this.getUser.displayName + " leaving " + this.getProfile);
  console.log(this.getProfile.data().clan);
  console.log(this.getProfile.data().clan.get().collection("members")
    .doc(this.getUser.uid));
  firebase
  .firestore().
  this.getProfile.data()
    .clan
    .get()
    .collection("members")
    .doc(this.getUser.uid)
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("profiles")
        .doc(this.getUser.uid)
        .update({
          clan: null
        });
    });
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out.

```
  this.getProfile
    .data()
    .clan.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
    });
```

just .get() or whatever normal firebase operation you would do. The field with the reference is essentially the doc reference as well.

I am sure there is a better answer that explains why this works or the right terms but it works haha.